# Using Data type as Image

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

I extracted an artwork from MP3 audio file with `Data` type. I want to implement it in my app, but there is no way to initialise SwiftUI `Image` using `Data`. However, it is possible to initialise `Image` using `CGImage`: 
`Image.init(cgImage: CGImage, scale: CGFloat, label: Text)`
So how do I convert `Data` to `CGImage` or somehow convert `Data` to `Image`?

Comment: I found the solution!
Here it is:
`Image(CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(CGImageSourceCreateWithData((NSImage.init(data: YOURDATAOFIMAGE as! Data)?.tiffRepresentation!)! as CFData, nil).unsafelyUnwrapped, Int(0), nil).unsafelyUnwrapped, scale: 1, label: Text(""))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `uiImage` initializer.

```
Image(nsImage: UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
```

Update: Use `nsImage` initializer for macOS.

```
Image(nsImage: NSImage(data: data) ?? NSImage(named: "placeholder"))
```

Comment: I get an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'UIImage'

Comment: Either unwrap or provide a default placeholder image.

Comment: Take a look at the error, please: https://i.ibb.co/d5XPDBd/Screenshot-2020-07-07-at-22-17-28.png

Comment: Dude just `import UIKit` on top of the file.

Comment: I get error when I import it: No such module 'UIKit'

Comment: because I am developing this app on Mac